# How to add Hibernate jar to Liberty Sample application in Bluemix?

Tags: hibernate, ibm-cloud, websphere-liberty

I created a sample application in Bluemix using the Liberty Profile.  Everything works.  I am editing the code in Bluemix, changed up the output and it all worked.

Now I want to add some libraries.  There is no where to put the jar file?

What folder structure do I need to create?
I guess I need to also edit pom.xml to configure the build.

Anyone done this before?

Answer (score 1):

You can add jars to the lib folder under the WebContent directory so they are accessible once the packaged server is deployed.

Once deployed, you'll find the jars in the following directory:

```
/home/vcap/app/wlp/usr/servers/defaultServer/apps/myapp.war/WEB-INF/lib/hello.jar
```